# Populate table with two JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tabular

I want to create table with two JSON. I can set fields in normal JSON, But these are more complex. Can you give me an idea?

Here is my json:

```
    {
  "ParentId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "UserGroupModel": null,
  "EntityAccessData": [
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "68c59596-12b5-4044-bd8c-2f754c44466f",
      "EntityTitle": "Message",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "8626c003-c3cb-4074-b3ff-6385b4d9e90e",
        "Title": "Can read"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "62b71a6e-6e74-4a8c-b6cb-f5ad21278e4f",
      "EntityTitle": "Message",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "e3b29357-8018-4438-88d5-7e80117aefc2",
        "Title": "Can add"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "7e99490b-4073-406d-a617-ce4c9014f3d4",
      "EntityTitle": "Message",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "b300e4f0-85bc-43ac-a50c-be3e7b288012",
        "Title": "Can delete"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "dde7e245-57d5-492d-b2c4-7ca9a55c6a41",
      "EntityTitle": "Message",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "d1310106-bb55-4cdf-a113-f8818b496588",
        "Title": "Can edit"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "88494116-cc2b-4028-9940-a8cf5d645602",
      "EntityTitle": "User",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "2f6744e2-a8fb-45b1-a67c-38f23def4149",
        "Title": "Can read"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "d1a6aaf2-b159-461a-8c9f-be9125cb683f",
      "EntityTitle": "User",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "a13677ea-fee3-4708-94e7-b0907ade304c",
        "Title": "Can add"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "112086ed-6a4f-47c0-8f16-9b56f37bda80",
      "EntityTitle": "User",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "aa283b4b-393e-4da5-a3c3-ba92a1b460a6",
        "Title": "Can edit"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "5f09c8f5-ff9d-4890-bcf9-9820fab5997f",
      "EntityTitle": "User",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "59d0c6f7-8f93-497a-854d-bdd4a42ade94",
        "Title": "Can delete"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "c206663f-a81f-437f-8213-99b2df7b5b7c",
      "EntityTitle": "Category",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "c5e672b5-e306-4181-ae37-93b50fb7bf20",
        "Title": "Can add"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "6a3546c0-b7e9-4a65-8033-801ee867be5f",
      "EntityTitle": "Category",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "3724d57c-b0e9-47a0-9eef-cb690f7c4837",
        "Title": "can read"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "636fac3f-9f53-47bd-9b46-af6d0e80366d",
      "EntityTitle": "Category",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "76e6b578-cb3a-4055-a582-e7269e46184b",
        "Title": "Can edit"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    },
    {
      "Id": null,
      "Title": null,
      "EntityAccessDataId": "757036a8-aea8-4151-a5e1-618352f9bcab",
      "EntityTitle": "Category",
      "SiteId": "1294900c-d8d9-4357-b698-001cbeac0231",
      "SiteTitle": "MYWEBSITE",
      "UserGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "UserGroupTitle": null,
      "Access": {
        "Id": "336f6f9b-c69a-4578-8b1e-f52442555000",
        "Title": "Can delete"
      },
      "Category": null,
      "HasAccess": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Dropdown's items will be come from this json

```
[
  {
    "Title": "-"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Yes"
  },
  {
    "Title": "No"
  }
]
```

How can I create table like this:

And here is my goal:

```
|---------------Title---------------|-------------------ID---------------|-----Access-----|
___________________________________________________________________________________________
|Message-----------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------
|can read---------------------------|8626c003-c3cb-4074-b3ff-6385b4d9e90e|-----DROPDOWN---|
|can add----------------------------|e3b29357-8018-4438-88d5-7e80117aefc2|-----DROPDOWN---|
|can delete-------------------------|b300e4f0-85bc-43ac-a50c-be3e7b288012|-----DROPDOWN---|
|can edit---------------------------|d1310106-bb55-4cdf-a113-f8818b496588|-----DROPDOWN---|
___________________________________________________________________________________________
|User--------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------
|can read---------------------------|2f6744e2-a8fb-45b1-a67c-38f23def4149|-----DROPDOWN---|
|can add----------------------------|a13677ea-fee3-4708-94e7-b0907ade304c|-----DROPDOWN---|
|can edit---------------------------|aa283b4b-393e-4da5-a3c3-ba92a1b460a6|-----DROPDOWN---|
|can delete-------------------------|59d0c6f7-8f93-497a-854d-bdd4a42ade94|-----DROPDOWN---|
___________________________________________________________________________________________
|Category----------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------
|can read---------------------------|c5e672b5-e306-4181-ae37-93b50fb7bf20|-----DROPDOWN---|
|can add----------------------------|336f6f9b-c69a-4578-8b1e-f52442555000|-----DROPDOWN---|
___________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: the dropdown json is bitconfusing.. you want all the rows to have that yes or no... or somrthing else... canu elaborate

Comment: how can i group by "EntityTitle" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `<table id="tableID">` to your document with the headers and append the generated `<tr>` to it..

say you json is data

try this

```
  var tempArray=[];
  var tableRow="";
 $.each(data.EntityAccessData,function(i,val){
     if(jQuery.inArray(val.EntityTitle, tempArray) == -1){
          tempArray.push(val.EntityTitle);
          var tableRow += '<tr><td>'+ val.EntityTitle  +'</td></tr>' 
     }else{
          var tableRow += '<tr><td>'+ val.Access.Id+'</td>'+'<td>'+val.Access.Title+'</td></tr>' 
     }
 })
 $('#tableID').append(tableRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/). You can load your JSON array into an `observableArray` (handy if you need to perform CRUD actions on it) and display your data in a using the custom `data-bind` attribute.